# How to append rows of a large pandas dataframe to a list without using for loops?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, dask-dataframe

This is an example of my dataframe:

```
    import pandas as pd
    
    data={'user':[10, 10, 10, 10, 10,10, 10,141.0,141.0,141.0,141.0,141.0,141.0,141.0,141.0,141.0,141.0],'trip':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,5],
          'Mode':['walk','walk','bus','bus','bus','bike','bike','bike','walk','car','car','walk','train','train','bike','car','car'],
          'lat':[39.979547,39.979558,39.979575,39.979587,39.979603,39.979547,39.979558,39.979575,39.979587,39.979603,39.979612,39.979627,39.979635,39.979645,39.979657,39.979670,39.979682], 
          'lon':[116.306813,116.306823,116.306835,116.306847,116.306852,116.306813,116.306823,116.306835,116.306847,116.306852,116.306867,116.306877,116.306888,116.306903,116.306913,116.306920,116.306920],
          'ts':[1235471761, 1235471763, 1235471765, 1235471767, 1235471778, 1235471780, 1235471782, 1235471784, 1235471786, 1235471788,1235471790,1235471812,1235471900,1235471920,1235471930,1235471942,1235471946]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df['TimeDistance'] = df.groupby('trip')['ts'].diff(1)
    m = df['TimeDistance'].gt(10).groupby(df['trip']).shift(fill_value=False)
    
    df['cum'] = (df['TimeDistance']
                 .mask(m, 0)
                 .groupby([df['trip'], m.cumsum()])
                 .cumsum()
                )
    df['cum'].iloc[0] = 0
    for i in range(len(df)-1):
      if df['trip'].iloc[i] != df['trip'].iloc[i+1]:
        df['cum'].iloc[i+1] = 0
    df
```

For each trip number in the 'trip' column, I want to append rows of the dataframe to a list whenever the value in the "cum" column reach m=10. To do that, I used a for loop with if statement, however, due to the large size of the real dataframe,over 5 million rows, after a while I got this error ‘’your session crashed after using all available RAM’’.
What I have done is this:
First, I created a list (result) based on trip numbers. In this list, each item is a dataframe with the same trip numbers:
(This "for loop" also works in the real dataframe with 5 million rows.)

```
result=[]
for i, j in df.groupby('trip'):
  if df['trip'].iloc[i+1] == df['trip'].iloc[i]:
    result.append(j)
```

and the output is something like this:

```
   [   user  trip  Mode        lat         lon          ts  TimeDistance   cum
 0  10.0     1  walk  39.979547  116.306813  1235471761           NaN   0.0
 1  10.0     1  walk  39.979558  116.306823  1235471763           2.0   2.0
 2  10.0     1   bus  39.979575  116.306835  1235471765           2.0   4.0
 3  10.0     1   bus  39.979587  116.306847  1235471767           2.0   6.0
 4  10.0     1   bus  39.979603  116.306852  1235471778          11.0  17.0
 5  10.0     1  bike  39.979547  116.306813  1235471780           2.0   0.0
 6  10.0     1  bike  39.979558  116.306823  1235471782           2.0   2.0,
     user  trip  Mode        lat         lon          ts  TimeDistance  cum
 7  141.0     2  bike  39.979575  116.306835  1235471784           NaN  0.0
 8  141.0     2  walk  39.979587  116.306847  1235471786           2.0  2.0
 9  141.0     2   car  39.979603  116.306852  1235471788           2.0  4.0,
      user  trip  Mode        lat         lon          ts  TimeDistance   cum
 10  141.0     3   car  39.979612  116.306867  1235471790           NaN   0.0
 11  141.0     3  walk  39.979627  116.306877  1235471812          22.0  22.0,
      user  trip   Mode        lat         lon          ts  TimeDistance   cum
 12  141.0     4  train  39.979635  116.306888  1235471900           NaN   0.0
 13  141.0     4  train  39.979645  116.306903  1235471920          20.0  20.0,
      user  trip  Mode        lat         lon          ts  TimeDistance   cum
 14  141.0     5  bike  39.979657  116.306913  1235471930           NaN   0.0
 15  141.0     5   car  39.979670  116.306920  1235471942          12.0  12.0
 16  141.0     5   car  39.979682  116.306920  1235471946           4.0   0.0]
```

After that, for each item in the ‘’result’’ I want to append rows that the value in the “cum“ column is greater than m=10.
(This "for loop" doesn’t work in the real dataframe with 5 million rows.)

```
    window=[]
    m = 10;
    for item in result:
      c = 0;
      for i in range(len(item)):
        if  item.iloc[i]["cum"] >= m:
            window.append(item[c:i+1])
            c=i+1
    window
```

and finally my desired output will be like this:

```
       [   user  trip  Mode        lat         lon          ts  TimeDistance   cum
     0  10.0     1  walk  39.979547  116.306813  1235471761           NaN   0.0
     1  10.0     1  walk  39.979558  116.306823  1235471763           2.0   2.0
     2  10.0     1   bus  39.979575  116.306835  1235471765           2.0   4.0
     3  10.0     1   bus  39.979587  116.306847  1235471767           2.0   6.0
     4  10.0     1   bus  39.979603  116.306852  1235471778          11.0  17.0,
          user  trip  Mode        lat         lon          ts  TimeDistance   cum
     10  141.0     3   car  39.979612  116.306867  1235471790           NaN   0.0
     11  141.0     3  walk  39.979627  116.306877  1235471812          22.0  22.0,
          user  trip   Mode        lat         lon          ts  TimeDistance   cum
     12  141.0     4  train  39.979635  116.306888  1235471900           NaN   0.0
     13  141.0     4  train  39.979645  116.306903  1235471920          20.0  20.0,
          user  trip  Mode        lat         lon          ts  TimeDistance   cum
     14  141.0     5  bike  39.979657  116.306913  1235471930           NaN   0.0
     15  141.0     5   car  39.979670  116.306920  1235471942          12.0  12.0]
```

The last for loop does not work in real dataframe. As you can see, I have defined a list (window= []) to append the rows to the list and the problem is that because the real dataframe is too large after running this loop I get a memory error in google colab, so, I think one solution that could be helpful is to append the rows to the “window list” until the length of the list arrives to a certain value and after that store this smaller window separately in the memory. After that continue to append other rows in a new list, let say for example window_2, until we reach threshold and store it again, however, I don’t know how to implement this. In other words, I want to append rows in some smaller lists instead of just appending in just one list. I am new in python and I don’t know it is possible or not. if you have other suggestions, please let me know.

Comment: `numpy` 'vectorization' does not help with memory issues.

Comment: @hpaulj Thank you for your response. Do you have any idea what should I do to solve this issue?

Comment: `pandas.Series.shift` and `numpy.where` should sort this all out